# Calling event between projects ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filter, layer

I have an ASP.NET project which is divided into 3 layers: Filter, Filter.Data and Filter.Task

Filter has a controller which calls the Filter.Task who calls the models in Data.
Task return the data to the controller.

I want to call my DatabaseFilter class when any function in Filter.Task returns data.

Is this possible?

I tested with HttpApplication.BeginRequest, but I can't check if the code is from Task

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use an action filter like so:

```
public class DatabaseActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result;

        var model = result.ViewData.Model;
    }
}
```

Then analyse the model for an instance of your data type and call your DatabaseFilter class accordingly?

You could then just add it as an attribute to the top of your controller methods:

```
[DatabaseAction]
public ActionResult MyControllerMethod()
```

Hope this helps and that I interpreted your question correctly.

Comment: thanks for your anwser, but I can't do this. I am not using an ActionResult, but a normal function called   public static List<Person> GetActivePersons() so an ActionFilter can't be used